# Avoir pour ( a pour) ==> signification ?

Tags: sens, traduction, locutions

J'ai rencontré plusieurs fois des phrases contenant **"a pour"**(avoir pour), mais je ne comprends pas exactement le rôle ou la fonction de cette composante *(locution verbale)* *(je pense que l'expression "avoir pour objectif / but " = cibler, viser à ... mais le problème que j'ai, c'est le cas "avoir +pour +nom ou quelque chose ")*

La dernière phrase que j'ai rencontrée "l’endomorphisme qui **a pour** matrice dans la base canonique, une équation".

Comment: Notre organisation a pour objectif de [Y]. = L'objectif de notre organisation est  de [Y]. Aussi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Soit Φ l’endomorphisme **qui a pour** matrice dans la base canonique de C<sup>4</sup> l'équation ...

est équivalent à :

> Soit Φ l’endomorphisme **dont la** matrice dans la base canonique de C<sup>4</sup> **est** l'équation ...

Une forme similaire à *avoir pour* est *avoir comme* :

> Soit Φ l’endomorphisme **qui a comme** matrice dans la base canonique de C4 l'équation ...

Voici deux autres phrases équivalentes sur le même modèle :

> L'Espagne est le pays **qui a pour** capitale Madrid.
> L'Espagne est le pays **dont la** capitale **est** Madrid.

On peut aussi dire :

> L'Espagne est le pays **qui a** Madrid **pour** capitale.
> L'Espagne est le pays **dont** Madrid est **la** capitale.

Comment: a pour = dont, Merci infiniment

Answer (score 1):

Cet usage est justifié dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) comme suit.

> **I.** − Emploi trans. Être en relation (concrète ou abstraite, permanente ou occasionnelle) avec quelqu'un ou quelque chose.
> **A.** − [Le suj. désigne une pers., l'obj. désigne soit une chose concr. ou abstr., soit une pers. dont on peut disposer]
> **1.** **[Avec l'idée de pouvoir en tirer profit ou parti, d'en jouir]** Synon. posséder.
> a) [L'obj. désigne un bien matériel] Être en possession de... Avoir un compte en banque, une maison, des rentes; avoir beaucoup d'argent :
>
> − [Avec un subst., attribut de l'obj., précédé des prép. **comme** et **pour**]
> ♦ Avoir pour chef M. X, avoir comme secrétaire Mlle Y :
> ♦ Pour guide nous avons une vierge au teint pâle Qui jamais ne reçut le baiser d'or du hâle Des lèvres du soleil. T. Gautier, La Comédie de la mort,1838, p. 28.
> ♦ ... nous avions pour professeur de rhétorique M. Collignon à qui ma reconnaissance reste acquise, ... Barrès, Mes cahiers,t. 4, 1906, p. 168.
> ♦ À Paris, tout le monde descend. La scène suivante se passe chez Lévy. MmeLévy demande à son mari s'il a fait bon voyage. « Pas mauvais, répond Lévy; mais j'avais pour compagnon de wagon un antisémite... » Gide, Ainsi soit-il,1951, p. 1189.

Dans le cas d'une matrice, on dirait difficilement qu'elle *possède* un endomorphisme, mais l'idée est assez générale ; on dira très bien qu'à la matrice est associé un endomorphisme ou l'endomorphisme *f*, et vice-versa.  Il s'agit donc d'une « possession » mutuelle. « La matrice a pour endomorphisme » est une expression un peu familière qui signifie la même chose que le plus formel « à la matrice est associé l'endomorphisme ».

On voit d'ailleurs que la définition globale reste dans l'esprit de cette idée d'association : « **Être en relation** (concrète ou **abstraite**, **permanente** ou occasionnelle) avec quelqu'un ou **quelque chose** ».